# Django and Smartmin default user?

Tags: python, django

I've installed a Django app that uses Smartmin.

I am on my Ubuntu server (14.04). It used django and Smartmin.

When I navigate to my default URL, I get a login screen. What I don't see is a place where I can create new users? I'm very new at Django/Smartmin and I'm really stuck.

I've googled, I've looked at the doc (like this: https://smartmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) but I'm just not finding how to create a new user - or if there is a default user?

Can someone familiar with django/smartmin point me in the right direction?

Is there more info I can give?

Edit: I have run `python manage.py createsuperuser` and I see the created user in my postgresql database.  My login fails when I log in with the user's info.

Edit: the URL I'm using is 127.0.0.1:8000. I'm using the python web server. 
I also ran syncdb before running the server.

Comment: What is the URL you are accessing?

Comment: I'm accessing the default URL - 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: You need to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` if you enabled the default admin; smartmin works on `http://127.0.0.1/users`

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me a 404 error. Do you know how I can enable the default admin?